# Is it possible to use Feature module for deleting modules?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I faced problem that I should do modules disable/uninstall, and only then go and remove modules from repo. I'm curios if that's possible to do with feature module?

I had a task to do some clean-up, remove few node types, uninstall few modules. 
Let me describe: I have two environments, test and prod. they are synced by git. if I'd disable/uninstall and then delete modules on my local env, and then push it to prod env, actually I delete only modules here, but their tables, etc still in DB - since there was no uninstall action done. Is it possible to do such things with using features? let's say I uninstall modules on local, then create feature, upload it to prod,and modules will be uninstalled as well?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing that? A little more detail might help generate some answers.

Comment: I had a task to do some clean-up, remove few node types, uninstall few modules.
Let me describe: I have two environments, test and prod. they are synced by git.
if I'd disable/uninstall and then delete modules on my local env, and then push it to prod env, actually I delete only modules here, but their tables, etc still in DB - since there was no uninstall action done.
Is it possible to do such things with using features? let's say I uninstall modules on local, then create feature, upload it to prod,and modules will be uninstalled as well?

Comment: 32i, you should edit your question and add your additional description there, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of using features, you cannot properly deïnstall a module if you have removed its files.

The routines and actions to take when deïnstalling, are all in the .install file. If that one is not found by Drupal, it cannot run the deïnstallation actions inside it.

Once you have placed back the files you can simply have your features migration call [`drupal_uninstall_module()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--install.inc/function/drupal_uninstall_module/6). That will uninstall the modules you pass along to it.